# Extjs, collapsed form panel. Title not showing up

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I have a form panel in a border layout as follows:

```
{
    xtype: 'form',
    region: 'north',
    split: true,
    labelAlign: 'top',
    height: 130,
    autoScroll: true,
    collapsible: true,
    listeners: {
        'collapse': function () {
            Ext.getCmp('slider').setTitle('Filter Events By Time');
            // this is not working either
        }
    },
    //collapsed: true,
    id: 'slider',
    title: 'Filter Events By Time',
    border: true,
    html: {
        tag: 'div',
        style: '',
        children: [{
            tag: 'div',
            cls: 'slider_div',
            style: 'margin-right:50px;position:relative;float:left'
        }, {
            tag: 'div',
            cls: 'slider_unit',
            style: 'margin-top:10px'
        }, {
            tag: 'div',
            style: 'clear:left'
        }, {
            tag: 'div',
            cls: 'startDate',
            style: 'margin-right:30px;float:left'
        }, {
            tag: 'div',
            cls: 'endDate',
            style: ''
        }, {
            tag: 'div',
            style: 'clear:left'
        }]
    }
}
```

Now, when I collapse it using following code, the collapsed panel does not have a title. I can see the title if I expand the panel.

```
Ext.getCmp('slider').collapse(true);
```

How can I get title on a collapsed form panel?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two small things you need to fix:

1 Method [`collapse`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-collapse), does not take argument bool, but `collapse( [direction], [animate] )`, all optional.

2 Use [itemId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId) instead of `id`:

> An itemId can be used as an alternative way to get a reference to a
>   component when no object reference is available. Instead of using an
>   id with Ext.getCmp, use itemId with
>   Ext.container.Container.getComponent which will retrieve itemId's or
>   id's. Since itemId's are an index to the container's internal
>   MixedCollection, the itemId is scoped locally to the container --
>   avoiding potential conflicts with Ext.ComponentManager which requires
>   a unique id.

3 Fetch component reference using `this` inside of internal scope and use [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) outside of it. Like this:

```
this.setTitle('Filter Events By Tim  Collapsede');
```

and/or

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#slider')[0].collapse();
```

and also please create your components using [Ext.define](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-define), and then call them in your border layout using [alias/xtype](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-alias). :-)

### Here is a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MkMPG/) on fiddle

Comment: I am using Extjs 3.4, collapse method of which is taking a boolean argument. Check this link,   http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-collapse  I tried the 3rd point in my code but it is not working. I did not try the 2nd point because I am sure I am getting a correct component with id. I have seen that few things works well in extjs 4.x but not in extjs 3.x, I will try to see if that is the case here. However,your tips are very useful in general. Thanks for them.